# Stop toolbar from Activity getting displayed in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar

My activity's current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMainContainer"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So it is essentially just a toolbar and a FrameLayout (which is a container thats populated by Fragments). Because of this, every fragment ends up having this toolbar, which I only want in the `MainActivity`. How do I get around this? Some Fragments have their own toolbar, but because only the `FrameLayout` in the activity gets replaced by the fragment's layout, the activity's toolbar is always there.

If I give a fragment it's own toolbar, the activity's toolbar will still be displayed above the fragment's toolbar - I want it to replace the toolbar instead.

In my AndroidManifest I've set my theme to be `NoActionBar`.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your `first` fragment in `onViewCreated(..)` use this :-

```
 if (getActivity()!=null) 
      getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Also the visibility should be set again to VISIBLE in the onDestroyView

Comment: he says he doesnt require that toolbar in any other fragment !! @Valentun

Comment: he said he have only SOME fragments with it's own toolbars. BTW I think if fragment change the parent activity state, it should recover the original state after it is gone from screen

Comment: Whatever , i think the above solution meets his requirement ,anyway !! @Valentun

Comment: yeah, I just made I remark, which could be useful. You can add it to answer if u want. Anyway, your solution is correct

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks @SantanuSur and @Valentun!

Answer (score -1):

if you do not need toolbar in  activity. Delete this code from your layout :

```
<include android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/main_toolbar" layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>
```

Comment: But the author said he need to hide toolbar only in SOME fragments

Answer (score -1):

if you do not need toolbar in your activity. Delete this code from your layout

```
<include 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/main_toolbar" 
layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>
```